# Spring transaction management multi-thread issue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-transactions

I would like to ask for your help regarding the following issue.

I have a system where I use Spring and "TransactionTemplate" from that to manage DB transaction. The DB call is a simple one, it's for saving data or getting, it depends on it's an existing one or not. How it looks like in nutshell:

```
public void getOrCreate() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.execute(TransactionCallback<T> action)
}
```

It works fine until many threads use this function. So for example, 10 threads call this "getOrCreate" method (if the given data doesn't exist, the data will be created, otherwise the system will give back the data).
However, it doesn't work always because sometimes I get an exception about the DB cannot create the data (Cannot insert duplicate key row in object ). I use a unique key not the basic incremented one in DB so that's why the key can be the same for different data what I would like to process.

I think the problem the following.
Two threads use data with the same key. Both of them process the data and when the data should be committed in DB the slower one cannot be because the key already has existed therefore it throws an exception about that.

Do you have any ideal how I can manage this multi-thread issue? Is this TransactionTemplate thread-safe or can I make it for that? 
Maybe should I use this Spring transaction management in a different way?

I hope my problem is understandable and thanks for your help in advance.
Regards

Comment: Make sure the transaction uses isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`, so two different threads cannot get the current row at the same time.

Comment: I think the problem is about how the unique key generated, not about transaction, as  your description.

Comment: SERIALIZABLE is solved my issue. Thanks